# Curious: Disable jQuery and Javascript interactions unless user is logged in?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, authentication

Is it possible to disable jQuery and Javascript interactions unless the user is logged in?

At first I wanted to put all the interactions in a seperate file, and then load it in with PHP when the user is logged in, but is there a different way to do this, or would you think it's better to do the following:

Create a log-in screen before the user comes to the main part of the website.

Comment: What kind of code are you trying to disable? Be specific.

Comment: savage way : make an intentional js error, no more js can be executed after error

Comment: Don't add any script or js file until user is logged in. I think, there is not need for script until user is logged in. If user session is out, redirect the page to login page. Hope it works!!!

Comment: That's a bad idea @BenjaminPoignant

Comment: @BenjaminPoignant Hackiest hack of all the hacks in hacksville

Comment: I know, that's why I wrote 'savage way'

Comment: I was just trying to disable interactions such as click as I was curious wether or not this was possible, so far Leonidas' his answer came closest to what I was looking for, thanks for all your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have HTML5 now! Just create a HTML session or a php $COOKIE and control your javascript functions with a simple if statement.

#### WEB STORAGE

```
localStorage.setItem("is_logged_in", var);

if(is_logged_in){
    //all of your functions in here  
}
```

You can read more here http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

#### PHP

Easier way and personally my favorite is using PHP.

```
$var = "is_logged_in";
setcookie($var , time() + (86400 * 30), "/")
```

And then for the check:

```
<?php if(isset($_COOKIE[$var])) { ?>
    //all of your functions in here
<?php } ?>
```

You can read more here http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp

### EDIT

And ofcourse you can always instead of having a huge if statement you can disable all controls in a very smaller if.

```
<?php if(isset($_COOKIE[$var])) { ?>
     $('button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: WOW thats my very first accepted answer! Love you dude!

Comment: Congratulations, it's a good solution to check for cookies with php ^^

Comment: Yes it is a good practice but you have to alwasy check on the session variables. This results to be a pain if you have to do it by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Potentially if there is an object on the page present when you are logged in, that isn't if you are not, then you could wrap something like this around your JS code:

```
if ($('LoggedInElement').length) {
   // All my code
}
```

Comment: no unfortunately there isn't thank you for your answer though.

Comment: Could you not create something to show in php? I'm not a PHP coder myself but it could be something like `if (blnUserLoggedIn) { echo "Something" }`?

Comment: I guess that would be a solution, but I believe using cookies as suggested below would be better, thank you for your effort though.

Answer (score 0):

No. Disabling JavaScript is a browser function and cannot be controlled programmatically.

Comment: hmmm, is there a different way to block click events unless the user is logged in?

Comment: You could just include jQuery on pages accessible to those who are logged in. Not sure what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: i was just curious, i'am thinking about a one-page design where everything interesting happends on a main page